# Show Video / Audio Files on asp .net page

Tags: asp.net, flash

I want to play video / audio files on asp .net page.

client has following requirements

1) It can play all the popular formats

2) It can use installed player (if windows media player or any other) or it can run inside browser (i.e. Flash player)

I have already explored different options

i.e. silverlight, Windows media services & flash player

Among these three silverlight is discarded as there very few browsers having that plug in

please suggest some solution and if there are any limitation of that solution please suggets.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For the web I would suggest transcoding the video to H264 (use ffmpeg) and then serving with an RTMP server to Adobe Flash player which you can embed in a web page. There are many options for the server, including commercial and free.

You can also simply post the video and use http download or some of the implementations that fake http streaming.

**Open Source:**

FluorineFX http://fluorinefx.com/

Red5 http://osflash.org/red5

RubyIZUMI http://code.google.com/p/rubyizumi/

Kaltura http://osflash.org/kaltura

haxeVideo http://code.google.com/p/haxevideo

**Commercial:**

Adobe Flash Media Server http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/

Wowza http://www.wowzamedia.com